# Add an image in the right margin

Tags: graphics, margins

I can add text in the right margin:

```
\marginpar{test}
```

But how can I add an image.png in the right margin?

Comment: `\marginpar{\includegraphics{image}}`

Comment: You might want to use [width=\marginparwidth] with that.

Answer (score 9):

I made the `sidenotes` package for this purpose. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sidenotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % provides the dummy text
\usepackage{mwe} % provides the example image

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{This is in the margin.}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: marginfigure image]

You can find more information using the package manual or you can use `\documentclass{caesar_book}` if you want to start with reasonable margin widths and such. There is a `tufte-book` class as well and I believe that `memoir`provides this functionality as well.