# How to add figure in the left margin?

Tags: floats, margins

I found a post about adding figure to the right margin, which works pretty well.

[Add an image in the right margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262044/add-an-image-in-the-right-margin)

However, I don't know the commands for adding a figure to the left margin.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a example with the mwe you gave. Important is the `\reversemarginpar`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % provides the dummy text
\usepackage{mwe} % provides the example image
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{This is in the margin.}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can also switch back and forth with `\reversemarginpar` and `\normalmarginpar`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % provides the dummy text
\usepackage{mwe} % provides the example image
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{This is in the margin on the left.}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\normalmarginpar
\begin{marginfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is in the margin on the right}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```