# How to create a similar box to be inserted in side notes?

Tags: boxes, box

I want to create some side notes similar to this one, but I have no idea what package should I use to design it ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can't find a good thumbtack image, you can make one with tikz/standalone and save the PDF for reuse.

Comment: Maybe [graphics - Add an image in the right margin - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262044/add-an-image-in-the-right-margin) plus you looking for some image.